# mod_rewrite: replace character in querystring?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-html-snapshot to create static snapshots of my Angular webapp. The site is driven by a CMS which is using the follow hierarchy

```
/ (page)
/somecateogry (page)
/somecategory/somepage (page)
/somecategory/anotherpage (page)
```

The problem is that grunt stores the snapshots of pages in categories with underscore, for example **snapshot____somecategory_somepage.html**.

Using the rewrite rule provided I'm able to reach the snapshot of a category page: **domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/category**. This gets rewritten to **/snapshots/snapshot____category.html**.

Subpages however, which I'm having problems with, gets rewritten to **/snapshots/snapshot____category/subpage.html**.

To be perfectly honest I have no real experience using mod_rewrite (I've gotten to where I am now largely thanks to this [article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)), so I feel listing what I've tried to be a bit futile. However, I hope I'm right in thinking that I somehow need to get the QueryString and then rewrite all slashes (/) to underscores. I'm also a bit concerned what will happen if I ever add subcategories, but that isn't to important for now.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot "/var/node-www/hornet"

  # Snapshot directory (Crawling directory)
  RewriteLog "/var/node-www/hornet/rw-log"
  RewriteLoglevel 4
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/snapshot____%1.html? [NC,L]

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName local.hornet
  ServerAlias local.hornet

  # Send to Tomcat
  ProxyPass /rest/ http://localhost:8080/Hornet/rest/
  ProxyPassReverse /rest/ http://localhost:8080/Hornet/rest/
  # Send to Node
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I'm in a similar boat right now.

Comment: As far as I recall I ended up changing the structure in lack of a real solution.